# Astro Js @font-face import build wrong replacement

Tags: javascript, css, vite, astrojs

I'm building an Astro Js project, I wan't to import a css file (for icons) from a dependency which include their own font files :

```
// @icons/dist/.../index.css
@font-face {
    font-family: "font name";
    src: url("./icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("./icons.woff") format("woff"),
url("./icons.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

When building I have a replacement which is not including the font file in the dist folder, the compiled css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font name';
    src: url(__VITE_ASSET__e6e97650__$_?6cdb7df3dc807c5592752bbd5d1c724e__) format('truetype'),
        url(__VITE_ASSET__bc194da8__$_?6cdb7df3dc807c5592752bbd5d1c724e__) format('woff'),
        url(__VITE_ASSET__c837e718__$_?6cdb7df3dc807c5592752bbd5d1c724e__) format('woff2');
}
```

Does anyone had this issue and know how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If `icons.ttf` is inside the public folder, the url should be: `url("/icons.ttf")`

Basically you need to remove the dot so it target the public folder instead of the folder where you have the CSS file.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you are deploying to a subfolder... :(

Comment: You may want to edit the astro.config.mjs to 
`export default defineConfig({
  site: "https://yourdomain.com/subfolder",
});`

Comment: that's the old syntax that won't work with newer Astro versions; but it doesn't work with the new style `export default defineConfig({site: "https://yourdomain.com/", base: "/subfolder/", ...}` syntax either.